# How can I log the timezone with Log::Log4perl?

Tags: perl, logging, timezone, log4perl

We use [Log::Log4perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl) to log the current date like this:

```
log4perl.appender.perllog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMdd.hhmmss:}-%P-%H-%p{2}-%m
```

Is there a way to log the timezone as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date formats in [Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout) are implemented by [Log::Log4perl::DateFormat](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::DateFormat)
, which supports the `Z` specifier for timezone offset:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Log::Log4perl;

my $conf = <<'CONF';
    log4perl.logger.Foo = INFO, perllog

    log4perl.appender.perllog          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
    log4perl.appender.perllog.filename = foo.log
    log4perl.appender.perllog.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
    log4perl.appender.perllog.layout.ConversionPattern = \
        %d{yyyyMMdd.hhmmssZ:}-%P-%H-%p{2}-%m
CONF

Log::Log4perl::init(\$conf);

my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('Foo');
$logger->warn('Hello, timezone!');
```

Output:

```
20160831.094036-0600:-28223-www.example.com-WA-Hello, timezone!
```

This is not documented in Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout; generally it's a bad idea to use undocumented features, but in this case it looks like the author just forgot to update the docs in one module when features were added to another. I've submitted [a ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=117377) to get the docs updated.